# MPMoviePlayerViewController with dropbox URL error: _itemFailedToPlayToEnd:

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, dropbox

I get the above error with the following code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/crzu6yrwt35tgej/flexao.mp4?dl=1" isDirectory:NO];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```

When I copy the file to my `bundle` and load the `url` from there it works.

I guess it has something to do with my dropbox link, but I also don't know how to generate a different link or filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as below

//You're using the URL https://www.dropbox.com/s/crzu6yrwt35tgej/flexao.mp4, but that's not a link to a video... it's a link to a page with a video on it.

To convert it to a direct link to the video, change www.dropbox.com to dl.dropboxuser.com, like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/crzu6yrwt35tgej/flexao.mp4

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/crzu6yrwt35tgej/flexao.mp4"];

self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```

Hope it fixes the issue..!

Comment: Remove ?dl=1 in the url string and try..!I modified the code.

Comment: Check my modified answer..@Jorge

Comment: Hi @Vidhyanand900 , I have a similar problem, basically, now I need to stream the video from dropbox, changing the quality according to user's connection, but if I change the code to `MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming`, it doesn't work.